# Rails app, relation between Product, Category and Brand?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

sorry for bothering you with basic question. I built an app like a e-commerce for electronics. I have 3 models: `product, category and brand`. On controllers is a mess but is working. On left side I have 2 `each.do  list`, one for `category` and other for `brand`. On rest of page I have all `products`. When I choose `TV category` it give me all `tv` which is good (it is on `http://localhost:3000/**categories**/8` page), when I'm choose let's say LG brand it give me all `LG : Tv , Phones....etc.` (it is on `http://localhost:3000/**brands**/6`  page) and I want just all LG TV's. I believe my problem is from conception so I made a mess from beginning.

category model :

```
has_many :products, dependent: :destroy 
has_many :brands
```

product model:

```
belongs_to :category  
belongs_to :brand
```

brand model:

```
has_many :products   
belongs_to :category
```

Can you give me an advice how start build this correct (just a outline) or maybe to tell me what kind of gems you are using for that. I don't know if my problem is from relations or filtering.

Thank you all.

Comment: what is the code that you've written in brands controller for listing?

Comment: def index
      @brands = Brand.all.order('name ASC')
end

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is the relationship between brands and categories. It's many-to-many instead of one-to-many.

brand model:

```
has_many :products
has_many :categories, through: products
```

category model:

```
has_many :products
has_many :brands, through: productions
```

product model:

```
belongs_to :brand
belongs_to :category
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a category link you are calling the show method for this category. When you click on a brand, you are calling the show method for this brand. Both show methods list all products for the category (or brand) but do not remember the previous filter (brand or category). Your links for category or brand should also pass the brand or category already filtered. You could do it by defining two instance variable in show methods, this way:

CategoriesController

```
def show
  @brand = params[:brand]
  @cat = params[:cat]
  #find the category or brand to show as usual. 
  @category = Category.find_by(id: params[:id])

  products = @category.products.where(brand_id: @brand)

end
```

Almost the same for BrandsController, filtering by category_id: @cat

And then, in the links:

```
<%= link_to @category.name, category_path(@category.id, cat: @cat, brand: @brand) %>
```

The same for the brand link

EDIT

You must also change models as Sean says.